# How should I detect collisions with objects on a "timeline"?

Tags: c#, unity, collision-detection, timing

I'd like to replicate [this game](http://www.silvergames.com/break-the-wall)'s mechanic of the player smashing walls with a precise timing to a background rhythm.

How should I check when each wall should be broken? Does the player animation use a hitbox, or does it use timing to detect if the smashing animation should play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only simple collision detection for something like this:
You could just compare the X-coordinate of the nearest wall with that of the player when the player throws a punch.

Something along the lines of

```
if (wall.x - player.x <= 50 && wall.x - player.x > 0) {
    // The wall is in a good position!
} else {
    // The wall is out of reach!
}
```

I used 50 as the maximum target distance here. Change it to fit the needs of your game.

If you would want this to be a part of an animation, just run this check in select frames of your animation, where the player's punch would be valid.